# Entity Framework where clause on related data is missing columns

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have 2 tables TableA and TableB that are linked with an ID column. This is a 1:N relationship. I have the following code

```
var query = from b in _ctx.TableA
                .Where(b => b.Flag == true)
                .Include(c => c.TableB)
            select b;
```

This produces the following select statement correctly displays my data in master-detail grids:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[C5] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[ProductType] AS [ProductType], 
    [Project1].[Ccy] AS [Ccy], 
    [Project1].[Flag] AS [Flag], 
    [Project1].[C6] AS [C6], 
    [Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1]

    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
        [Extent1].[ProductType] AS [ProductType], 
        [Extent1].[Flag] AS [Flag], 
        1 AS [C5], 
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Extent2].[Ccy] AS [Ccy], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C6]
        FROM  [dbo].[TableA] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TableB] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
        WHERE (1 = [Extent1].[Flag]) AND ([Extent1].[Flag] IS NOT NULL)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC, [Project1].[C6] ASC
```

Now, I would like to filter out on my navigation property (TableB). I tried the following 3 ways and I am getting the following SQL back with all 3 ways but it is missing the columns from TableA, like ProductType and Ccy.

```
var query = from b in _ctx.TableA
.Where(b => b.Flag == true)
.Include(c => c.TableB).Select(o => o.TableB.Where(od => od.Ccy == "USD"))
select b;

var query = from b in _ctx.TableA
.Where(b => b.Flag == true)
.Include(c => c.TableB)
.SelectMany(o => o.TableB.Where(od => od.Ccy == "USD"))
select b;


var query = from p in _ctx.TableA
join ps in _ctx.TableB on p.Id equals ps.Id
where ps.Ccy == "USD"
select new { p, ps };
```

```
SELECT [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
    [Project1].[Ccy] AS [Ccy], 
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Extent2].[Ccy] AS [Ccy], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[TableA] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TableB] AS [Extent2] 
        ON ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]) 
        AND ('USD' = [Extent2].[Ccy]) AND ([Extent2].[Ccy] IS NOT NULL)
        WHERE (1 = [Extent1].[Flag]) AND ([Extent1].[Flag] IS NOT NULL)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

How can I modify the one of the 3 queries above to have these columns included:

```
[Project1].[ProductType] AS [ProductType], 
[Project1].[Ccy] AS [Ccy], 
[Project1].[Flag] AS [Flag],
```

I understand that the navigation property is not meant to be able to filter but these queries are correct except for the missing columns on TableA.

I used tables to simplify the code. I will detail how I am displaying the master - detail grids so you can see the data context being used. I simplified the actual code so only pertinent details. Hopefully, this will clarify how the current code is working. I'm not sure how I am supposed to modify the xaml in order to make the binding work without getting these errors:

```
   [Table("viewA")]
    public class Master
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Investment()
        {
            Prices = new HashSet<CcyHistory>();
        }

        [StringLength(150)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(150)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public bool? Flag { get; set; }


        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

        public ICollection<CcyHistory> Details { get; set; }
    }


    [Table("viewB")]
    public class CcyHistory
    {

        [Key]
        [StringLength(150)]
        [Column(Order = 0, TypeName = "varchar")]
        public string Id { get; set; }


        [StringLength(10)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        public string Ccy { get; set; }


        public virtual Master Master { get; set; }
    }


    public partial class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext()
            : base("name=MyContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Master> Masters { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CcyHistory> Details { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

        }
    }




    public partial class MyView : Window
    {
        MyViewModel viewModel;

        public MyContext _ctx = new MyContext();

               .......


         public MyView()
        {
            viewModel = new MyViewModel();

            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = viewModel;
        }

        private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource myViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("myViewSource")));


            // this works fine
            var query = from b in _ctx.Masters
                       .Where(b => b.Flag == true)
                       .Include(c => c.Details)
                       select b;


            // this query cannot be bound to xaml
            //var query = from a in _ctx.Masters
            //            .Where(a => a.Flag == true)
            //            .Select(a => new
            //            {
            //                Details = a,
            //                USD = a.Details.Where(od => od.Ccy == "USD").ToList()
            //            })
            //            select a;


           myViewSource.Source = query.ToList();


XAML:

        <Window.Resources>
                <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myViewSource" d:DesignSource="d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Masters},CreatList=True}"/>

            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myDetailsViewSource" Source="{Binding Details, Source={StaticResource myViewSource}}">
            </CollectionViewSource>
            </Window.Resources>

        .....

            <Grid Name="MyGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource myViewSource}" >


                       <igDP:XamDataGrid x:Name="masterGrid" Grid.Row="1" DataSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">

                            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings Width="Auto" AllowEdit="False"/>
                            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>

                            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                                <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False" SelectionTypeRecord="Extended" SelectionTypeCell="None" />
                            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>

                            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                                <igDP:FieldLayout>

                                    <igDP:UnboundField Name="ID" BindingPath="Id" BindingMode="TwoWay">
                                        <igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                                            <igDP:FieldSettings CellClickAction="SelectRecord">
                                            </igDP:FieldSettings>
                                        </igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                                    </igDP:UnboundField>


                                    <igDP:UnboundField Name="Description" BindingPath="Description" BindingMode="TwoWay">
                                        <igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                                            <igDP:FieldSettings CellClickAction="SelectRecord">
                                            </igDP:FieldSettings>
                                        </igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                                    </igDP:UnboundField>

                                    <igDP:UnboundField Name="Held" BindingPath ="Flag">
                                        <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                            <igDP:FieldSettings CellClickAction="SelectRecord"/>
                                        </igDP:Field.Settings>
                                    </igDP:UnboundField>


                                </igDP:FieldLayout>
                            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>

                        </igDP:XamDataGrid>



                        <igDP:XamDataGrid x:Name="detailsDataGrid" Grid.Row="2" DataSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDetailsViewSource}}" >


                            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings Width="Auto" AllowEdit="False"/>
                            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>

                            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                                <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False" SelectionTypeRecord="Extended" SelectionTypeCell="None" />
                            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>

                            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                                <igDP:FieldLayout>

                                    <igDP:UnboundField Name="ID" BindingPath="Id"  Width="Auto" BindingMode="TwoWay">
                                        <igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                                            <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" CellClickAction="SelectRecord">
                                            </igDP:FieldSettings>
                                        </igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                                    </igDP:UnboundField>


                                    <igDP:UnboundField Name="Ccy"  BindingPath="Ccy"  Width="Auto" >
                                        <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                            <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" />
                                        </igDP:Field.Settings>
                                    </igDP:UnboundField>

                                </igDP:FieldLayout>
                            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>

                        </igDP:XamDataGrid>

                    </Grid>
```

For example, one of the errors I'm getting is:

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Description' property not found on 'object' ''<>f__AnonymousType0`2' (HashCode=580396885)'. BindingExpression:Path=Description; DataItem='<>f__AnonymousType0`2' (HashCode=580396885); target element is 'ValueHolder' (HashCode=62039823); target property is 'Value' (type 'Object')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, navigation properties in an entity cannot be filtered, although it is possible to apply a low level filter on the DbSet such as for IsActive or possibly tenancy. (TenantId in a multi-tenant system)

If you want the "A" record with only the "B" records that meet your criteria then the following will do that:

```
var query = from a in _ctx.TableA
.Where(a => a.Flag == true)
.Select(a => new 
{ 
    TableA = a,
    USDTableBs = a.TableB.Where(od => od.Ccy == "USD").ToList()
});
```

The key things to note:
The resulting object will include a TableA reference with the filtered set of TableBs. In the above example, the TableA.TableB references are not eager loaded. You can add a `.Include(a => a.TableB)` to load them, however whether eager or lazy loaded, TableA.TableB will *not* be filtered. It will represent all "B"'s associated with each "A". The filtered Bs are accessible using the USDTableBs collection returned alongside each TableA in the anonymous type.

So for instance:

```
var tableA = query.First().TableA;
var filteredBs = query.First().USDTableBs; // not tableA.TableBs
```

Edit: To bind to a data grid you're better off defining a ViewModel for the TableA and it's associated TableB records. If you were binding to a TableA originally, this new query returns an anonymous type so the old bindings for "ID" would not be correct. I don't recommend binding directly to Entities because even if you map to an entity and only load the filtered TableBs, it can be confusing if that filtered entity later tries to get attached to a DbContext and saved as it doesn't represent a complete picture of the entity.

To Bind to the anonymous type you would replace any bindings such as "Id" to "TableA.Id" etc. And any bindings for "TableB.x" to "USDTableBs.x". Alternatively with a ViewModel for TableA and it's associated TableBs, create a POCO TableAViewModel and TableBViewModel with just the fields your view will need and load them like:

```
var query = from a in _ctx.TableA
.Where(a => a.Flag == true)
.Select(a => new TableAViewModel
{ 
    Id = a.Id,
    // ... any fields from TableA to display...
    TableB = a.TableB
        .Where(od => od.Ccy == "USD")
        .Select(od => new TableBViewModel
        {
            Id = od.Id,
            Ccy = od.Ccy,
            // ... any fields from TableB to display ...
        }).ToList()
});
```

That should return a structure your WPF view would bind to in place of the Entities you were originally used. The advantage of the ViewModel approach is that you can filter them as needed, and optimize queries to just the amount of data needed, and don't need to worry about confusing them with Entities which could lead to bugs and errors down the road.

Edit:  Based on your provided details for the bindings you have 2 collection view sources. The first for the list of items and the 2nd for the details on the selected item:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="myViewSource" d:DesignSource="d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Masters},CreatList=True}"/>

        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myDetailsViewSource" Source="{Binding Details, Source={StaticResource myViewSource}}">
        </CollectionViewSource>
```

The bindings for the first view source are expecting to point at fields in the Masters entity. The bindings for the second are expecting a "Details" collection for the details. To structure your anonymous type structure, it should look something like:

```
var query = _ctx.Masters
                    .Where(a => a.Flag == true)
                    .Select(a => new
                    {
                        a.ID,
                        a.Description,
                        a.Flag 
                        Details = a.Details.Where(od => od.Ccy == "USD").ToList()
                    });
```

The difference here is the selected entities are the details from the master to match each master row as if it were bound to the master row. Your bindings are expecting fields on the returned collection items rather than an object containing those fields. The details section is expecting Master.Details, so in our case we still need to call it "Details" but rather than it binding to a.Details, it binds to our selected sub-set.

The alternative with your old Linq expression is rather than the individual binding to "Id", you would have needed to bind to "Details.Id" because you selected the Master record as "Details" and instead of binding the 2nd collection view source to "Details" you would have needed to bind it to "USD" based on how you selected that collection in the Linq.

Comment: I can see the correct query being executed. The problem that I am having is that I'm getting an error and therefore no records are being displayed. If I swith to my original query with no ccy filter on TableB all is good. I am using WPF and displaying in a datagrid. Here is the error I am getting:

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Id' property not found on 'object' ''<>f__AnonymousType0`2' (HashCode=-1011284684)'. BindingExpression:Path=Id; DataItem='<>f__AnonymousType0`2' (HashCode=-1011284684); target element is 'ValueHolder' (HashCode=51530997); target property is 'Value' (type 'Object')

Comment: Also, all that I did was the var query you suggested. I'm not sure I understood what you were suggesting with the var TableA and var filteredBs.

Comment: When I cut and paste the query in SSMS I get the exact same columns and column names. The only exception is the number of data records since I'm filtering out on the Ccy.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to cover off your binding issues. I believe you can still bind to an anonymous type, but I'd recommend using view models to represent your filtered models suited for your view.

Comment: I added more information to the code above. If you can take a look and see what needs to be changed in the xaml to make the query you suggested able to bind properly.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to provide a Linq expression that should work. Your example was close, but the returned structure didn't match what the bindings were expecting. My updated example should match the bindings you have, otherwise the binding expressions could be changed to match what you were selecting. Have a go with it and add an Updated section at the bottom of your question with the Linq and bindings along with any exception if you're still getting an error. Hopefully though that should be working now.

Comment: The linq expression you provided is working great. The only thing I had to do to the xaml for the bindings on 'MyGrid' to display the data was to revert to the xaml to just <Field> rather than <UnboundField>. I'm trying to use UnboundField so I can rename the column name. I'm suspecting I need to address Masters somewhere in the linq expression so that the xaml can bind to the unbound field properly but I'm not sure how to write that. Also, how would I go about passing a Ccy dynamically to the linq expression?

Comment: I figures out how to pass the Ccy dynamically. If you could help with getting Masters on the linq expression would be greatly appreciated as a final help with this thread.

Comment: I don't think you should need to use an UnboundField, simply select your desired naming in the `Select` statement or populate a view model. For the main bindings I'm not that familiar with collection view sources and "DesignSource" in particular. There does look like there is a typo there with `CreatList=True` rather than `CreateList=True`?  The Masters information should be in your results. Are you getting binding errors, or are some of the details just not displaying? (The details are displaying now?)

Comment: The details display perfectly using the UnboundField. I will get binding errors if I use the UnboundField with the Masters data. For now I'm just using Fields so that the Masters data displays. It would be a nice to have to be able to change the column names in the grid. Let me see if the typo has any effect.

Comment: Actually, removing BindingMode="TwoWay" from the UnboundField did the trick. So, I think all my issues have been addressed. EXCELLENT!